# 301 redirec folder - how i can redirect only exact url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have problem to redirect exact folder url.

```
Redirect 301 /folder1 /new/test1.html
Redirect 301 /folder1/sub3folder1 /new/test2.html
```

First line of code work properly, but I have problem with second line because I cant redirect exact url /folder1/sub3folder1 because first line already redirect to /new/test1.html and i have result /new/test1.html/test2.html instead of only /new/test2.com

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Redirect` directive doesn't support regex.

Yo can use `RedirectMatch` for regex support like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder1/?$ /new/test1.html
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder1/sub3folder1/?$ /new/test2.html
```

Answer (score 1):

What about just switching the two lines? ;) So the Apache will first try to match the first line and if no match is found then he goes further.

```
Redirect 301 /folder1/sub3folder1 /new/test2.html
Redirect 301 /folder1 /new/test1.html
```